# Parse Json Response to Multiple Objects C# unity

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I am trying to build Multiplayer game where Java is my server and Unity is my Clinet.
I am able to send data to server and read data in Json format in the server(Java Server) But when i try to read the response i am facing issues. I am unable to map properly the Json response to the Classes which are creatied in Unity.

Please find below.

```
public class Player
{
    public string playerID;
    public string name;
    public string playerPosX;
    public string playerPosY;
    public string playerPosZ;
}

public class Lobby 
{

    public string lobbyID;

    public ArrayList player;
}


lobby = JsonUtility.FromJson<Lobby>(response);
Debug.Log(lobby.lobbyID);
Debug.Log(lobby.player.Count);
```

I am getting the json data as

```
{"player":[{"playerID":"P1","name":"","playerPosX":"","playerPosY":"","playerPosZ":"","myne":false}],
"lobbyID":"L1"
}
```

and i am getting following error.
at 2nd log
Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you're locked into using the Unity Json utility, but I had success with your Json string using the [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) nuget library:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = "{\"player\":[{\"playerID\":\"P1\",\"name\":\"\",\"playerPosX\":\"\",\"playerPosY\":\"\",\"playerPosZ\":\"\",\"myne\":false}],\"lobbyID\":\"L1\"}";
            Lobby lobby = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Lobby>(json);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(lobby.lobbyID);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(lobby.player.Length);
        }
    }

    public class Lobby
    {
        public Player[] player { get; set; }
        public string lobbyID { get; set; }
    }

    public class Player
    {
        public string playerID { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string playerPosX { get; set; }
        public string playerPosY { get; set; }
        public string playerPosZ { get; set; }
        public bool myne { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
L1
1
```

Which is what I gather you're looking for.

Comment: If i use get and set its not working even Lobby ID is coming as null

Comment: I can see there is difference you are using Newtonsoft.Json but i am using UnityEngine.JsonUtility

Comment: Thanks mate working ! added these new libraries and it started working. The default Json parcer in Unity is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This structure should work, deserialize to type Lobby:

```
public class Player
{
    public string playerID;
    public string name;
    public string playerPosX;
    public string playerPosY;
    public string playerPosZ;
    public bool myne;
}

public class Lobby
{
    public List<Player> player;
    public string lobbyID;
}
```

Comment: Not working may be my Json api need to be changed i guess

Comment: Yeah Newtonsoft.Json is the better library, faster, less strict, well tested and Microsoft supported. Then just use JsonConvert class.